# Accesing SQL DB in Razor View -> Unable to cast string to Generic.List

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller, html-helper

I am trying to display the Lecturer attributes retrieved from SQL database and stored on the List on my Razor view but when it reaches the line:

```
foreach (var lec in (List<LecturerModel>)ViewData["lecturers"])
```

I get the error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ADO.Models.LecturerModel]'.'

## DATA

```
List<LecturerModel> Lecturers = new List<LecturerModel>();
string query = "SELECT * FROM Lecturer";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rd.Read())

{

    LecturerModel lecturer = new LecturerModel()
    {
        LecturerId = (int)rd["Id"],
        FirstName = (string)rd["FirstName"],
        LastName = (string)rd["LastName"],
        PracticeId = (int)rd["PracticeId"],
        SessionId = null 

    };

    Lecturers.Add(lecturer);

}
```

## CONTROLLER

```
        List<LecturerModel> Lecturers = LecturerData.GetLecturers();

        ViewData["Lecturers"] = "lecturers";


        return View();
    }
```

## VIEW

```
  @model ADO.Models.LecturerModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))

    {
        <table>
            @{

              foreach (var lec in (List<LecturerModel>)ViewData["lecturers"])
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@lec.FirstName</td>
                        <td>@lec.LastName</td>
                        <td>@lec.Username</td>
                    </tr>
                }

            }
        </table>
```

Comment: `ViewData["Lecturers"] = "lecturers";` <-- you are assigning a string literal to `ViewData["Lecturers"]`. In your other code, you are trying to cast this to `List<LecturerModel>` - clearly that isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is setting `ViewData["Lecturers"]` to the string literal "lecturers":

```
    List<LecturerModel> Lecturers = LecturerData.GetLecturers();
    ViewData["Lecturers"] = "lecturers";
```

Perhaps you wanted to assign the `List<LecturerModel>` to it instead?:

```
    List<LecturerModel> Lecturers = LecturerData.GetLecturers();
    ViewData["Lecturers"] = Lecturers;
```

<strike>This should make `(List<LecturerModel>)ViewData["lecturers"]` work.</strike>

[@Rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1807452/rahul-sharma) just mentioned in the comments that there's a casing difference:

In the code above, you're assigning a value to `ViewData["Lecturers"]`, but then  you're trying to read from `ViewData["lecturers"]` (notice the first L). These need to be the same. You should change your other piece of code to an uppercase `L` to match:

```
foreach (var lec in (List<LecturerModel>)ViewData["Lecturers"])
```

Comment: I am unable to edit your answer but this should be `(List<LecturerModel>)ViewData["Lecturers"]`

Comment: @Rahul I didn't notice OP's casing difference. You're right.